# While loop execution error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a problem in sql query. I have to execute sql query  in while loop.Below are my program

```
<?php
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $query = $db->query("Select * from cart");
    $query->execute();
    while($cd = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
?> 
<ul class="header-cart-wrapitem">
    <li class="header-cart-item">
        <div class="header-cart-item-img">
            <img src="images/item-cart-01.jpg" alt="IMG">
        </div>

        <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
            <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name"><?php 
            $aa = $cd['cat'];
            $ab = $cd['id2'];

            $query = $db->query("Select * from $aa where id = $ab ");
            $query->execute();
            $cdd1 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo $cd2 = $cdd1['detail'];
        ?></a>

        <span class="header-cart-item-info">
            <?php echo $cd['num'] ?> x 123
        </span>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

My second sql runs based on first sql.

**My problem**
I am getting only one row means it is executing only once.

**What I need**
I need all row.

Answer (score 2):

You're reusing the `$query` variable inside the loop. So when the loop repeats and does

```
while($cd = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

it's now fetching from the second query, not the original one.

Use a different variable inside the loop.

```
    $query2 = $db->query("Select * from $aa where id = $ab ");
    $query2->execute();
    $cdd1 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Thank you sir you save my time.

Answer (score 0):

You redefining `$query` inside of `while` scope. Yous use another variable (e.g. $query2 ) inside of the scope.